# Вывод отсортированных файлов

Tags: bat, сортировка

Через bat получаю список файлов директории, которая содержит из несколько тысяч штук

```
   dir /b z19\*.*
```

По идее, файлы должны быть отсортированы по имени, как на винде, но получается следующее:

В ОС, как и положено, файлы отсортированы по имени:
..
05_73
05_74
05_75
..

Но в батнике выводит следующее:
..
05_73
05_730
05_731
..

Как получить в bat результат, как в первом примере?